# Software to change the desktop background to the Windows Spotlight background

Tags: gratis, images, automation, windows-10

The [Windows 10 Spotlight Lock Screen](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/09/19/windows-10-tip-how-to-enable-windows-spotlight-images-on-your-lock-screen/#7fLRm36dG9MwxRfi.97) backgrounds are quite nice, and I would like to see them on my Desktop background in addition to them being on the Lock Screen. I'm looking for software to change the background on my desktop local account to the Spotlight Lock Screen background that meets these requirements,

- Gratis
- Windows 10 64 bit compatible
- Runs in the background with a low memory footprint
- Fully automatic (I don't have to rename images, copy/paste files, click buttons etc.) - set's the background to whatever today's Window's Spotlight is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time, but I've made this app to do the job,

## [Spotlight Desktop](https://wallpaper.onlineth.com/) ([open source](https://github.com/onlineth/Spotlight-Desktop))

> Simple app to change the desktop wallpaper to the Windows Spotlight Lock Screen image.
>
> [image: Spotlight Image on desktop and lock screen]

It meets my requirements and has the features of:

- Gratis - open source on GitHub
- Runs on my Windows 10 64 bit laptop
- Runs in the background without a large memory footprint
- Runs automatically with no human intervention required
- Checks for changes every minute
- Runs on startup automatically if installed with the installer